# "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop" no longer does "drop schema" after upgrading from Spring Boot 2.6.1 to 2.6.2

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I'm using Maven, Spring Boot, Hibernate, and PostgreSQL 11.
My application.properties file includes `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`, `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2dll.create_namespaces=true`, and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema="my_schema"`.

---

**Spring Boot 2.6.1** has a dependency on **Hibernate 5.6.1.Final**.
Using this version, here's what Hibernate did on startup:

1. drop tables if exist (they don't exist)
2. drop my_schema (which doesn't exist)
3. create my_schema
4. create tables
5. alter tables to add constraints

... and then on shutdown:

1. drop tables if exist (they do exist now)
2. drop my_schema (which does exist now)

---

**Spring Boot 2.6.2** has a dependency on **Hibernate 5.6.3.Final**.
Using this version, here's what Hibernate did on startup:

1. drop tables if exist (they don't exist)
2. create my_schema
3. create tables
4. alter tables to add constraints

... and then on shutdown:

1. drop tables if exist (they do exist now)

---

(Spring Boot versions 2.6.2 through 2.6.5 all seem to have the same behavior regarding this.)

Questions:

1. Is there any documentation explaining this change, which I assume happened in Hibernate 5.6.2 or Hibernate 5.6.3?
2. How can I get back the "drop schema" step on shutdown, when I'm using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`? (But of course, when I'm using a Spring profile that *doesn't* have the `create-drop` setting, then I wouldn't want "drop schema" to happen.)

Comment: I migrated from Spring 2.3.4 to 2.7.1. Same issue for me